# How set the option"inherited members" for projects with the rest-api from Redmine

Tags: redmine, redmine-api

I create automatically with the rest api a lot of projects in Redmine.

But we have the problem that for every project we need to set manually the option "inherited members from parent projects" (i don´t know exactly the right spelling). This is very disappointing.

This is the snippet how we create a project:

```
$client->api('project')->create(array(
                'name'     => $project_name,
                'identifier' => $project_identifier,
                'tracker_ids' => $tracker_ids,
                'parent_id' => $produktions_projekt_id));
```

This work´s nicely. But i want to add something like this:

```
'inherited members' => true
'inherited members' => 1
'inherited members' => '1'
```

I tried these three options, but they didn´t worked. I hope someone of you can help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it this way:

```
:inherit_members => '1'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes it does. It's framed as a question, but it's an answer, whether correct or otherwise.

Comment: yes i tried `inherit_members => '1'` and `inherit_members => 1` Both didn´t work. (I have added this code snippets in the question)